# Stream of Char to Stream of Byte/Byte Array

Tags: arrays, java-8, char, byte, java-stream

The following code takes a `String s`, converts into `char` array, filters digits from it, then converts it to `string`, then converts into `byte` array.

```
char charArray[] = s.toCharArray();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(charArray.length);
for(int i=0; i<=charArray.length-1; i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(charArray[i]))
        sb.append(charArray[i]);
}
byte[] bytes = sb.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

I'm trying to change the above code to streams approach. Following is working.

```
s.chars()
.sequential()
.mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch)
.filter(Character::isDigit)
.collect(StringBuilder::new,
        StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
.toString()
.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

I think there could be a better way to do it.

Can we directly convert `Stream<Character>` to `byte[]` & skip the conversion to `String` in between?

Comment: There is no `Stream<Character>` in your code. It’s an `IntStream`.

Comment: After `.mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch)` the `IntStream` is converted to `Stream<Character>`

Comment: Yes, but that step is entirely obsolete. Just remove it. Further, when you use `appendCodePoint`, you should also use `codePoints()` instead of `chars()`.

Comment: OK. But, still the question is can we skip the intermediate `Intstream` to `String` conversion ?

Comment: Also, I've changed `StringBuilder::appendCodePoint` to `StringBuilder::append`

Comment: You can omit the `toString()` when you use `CharBuffer.wrap(…)` on the resulting `StringBuilder` and the `Charset` for converting. It could be done more directly, however, creating a `byte[]` result is tricky in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, both of your variants have the problem of not handling characters outside the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) correctly.

To support these characters, there is `codePoints()` as an alternative to `chars()`. You can use `appendCodePoint` on the target `StringBuilder` to consistently use codepoints throughout the entire operation. For this, you have to remove the unnecessary `.mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch)` step, whose removal also eliminates the overhead of creating a `Stream<Character>`.

Then, you can avoid the conversion to a `String` in both cases, by encoding the `StringBuilder` using the `Charset` directly. In the case of the stream variant:

```
StringBuilder sb = s.codePoints()
    .filter(Character::isDigit)
    .collect(StringBuilder::new,
             StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append);

ByteBuffer bb = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(sb));
byte[] utf8Bytes = new byte[bb.remaining()];
bb.get(utf8Bytes);
```

Performing the conversion directly with the stream of codepoints is not easy. Not only is there no such support in the `Charset` API, there is no straight-forward way to collect a Stream into a `byte[]` array.

One possibility is

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = s.codePoints()
    .filter(Character::isDigit)
    .flatMap(c -> c<128? IntStream.of(c):
        c<0x800? IntStream.of((c>>>6)|0xC0, c&0x3f|0x80):
        c<0x10000? IntStream.of((c>>>12)|0xE0, (c>>>6)&0x3f|0x80, c&0x3f|0x80):
        IntStream.of((c>>>18)|0xF0, (c>>>12)&0x3f|0x80, (c>>>6)&0x3f|0x80, c&0x3f|0x80))
    .collect(
        () -> new Object() { byte[] array = new byte[8]; int size;
            byte[] result(){ return array.length==size? array: Arrays.copyOf(array,size); }
        },
        (b,i) -> {
            if(b.array.length == b.size) b.array=Arrays.copyOf(b.array, b.size*2);
            b.array[b.size++] = (byte)i;
        },
        (a,b) -> {
            if(a.array.length<a.size+b.size) a.array=Arrays.copyOf(a.array,a.size+b.size);
            System.arraycopy(b.array, 0, a.array, a.size, b.size);
            a.size+=b.size;
        }).result();
```

The `flatMap` step converts the stream of codepoints to a stream of UTF-8 unit. (Compare with the [UTF-8 description on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)) The `collect` step collects `int` values into a `byte[]` array.

It’s possible to eliminate the `flatMap` step by creating a dedicate collector which collects a stream of codepoints directly into a `byte[]` array

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = s.codePoints()
    .filter(Character::isDigit)
    .collect(
        () -> new Object() { byte[] array = new byte[8]; int size;
            byte[] result(){ return array.length==size? array: Arrays.copyOf(array,size); }
            void put(int c) {
                if(array.length == size) array=Arrays.copyOf(array, size*2);
                array[size++] = (byte)c;
            }
        },
        (b,c) -> {
            if(c < 128) b.put(c);
            else {
                if(c<0x800) b.put((c>>>6)|0xC0);
                else {
                    if(c<0x10000) b.put((c>>>12)|0xE0);
                    else {
                        b.put((c>>>18)|0xF0);
                        b.put((c>>>12)&0x3f|0x80);
                    }
                    b.put((c>>>6)&0x3f|0x80);
                }
                b.put(c&0x3f|0x80);
            }
       },
       (a,b) -> {
            if(a.array.length<a.size+b.size) a.array=Arrays.copyOf(a.array,a.size+b.size);
            System.arraycopy(b.array, 0, a.array, a.size, b.size);
            a.size+=b.size;
       }).result();
```

but it doesn’t add to readability.

You can test the solutions using a `String` like

```
String s = "some test text 1234 ✔ ３ ";
```

and printing the result as

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(utf8Bytes));
System.out.println(new String(utf8Bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

which should produce

```
[49, 50, 51, 52, -17, -68, -109, -16, -99, -97, -99]
1234３
```

It should be obvious that the first variant is the simplest, and it will have reasonable performance, even if it doesn’t create a `byte[]` array directly. Further, it’s the only variant which can be adapted for getting other result charsets.

But even the

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = s.codePoints()
    .filter(Character::isDigit)
    .collect(StringBuilder::new,
             StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
    .toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

is not so bad, regardless of whether the `toString()` operation bears a copying operation.

Comment: I doubt that many people (me including) will actually understand why and what you are doing in that big operation - I only have basic hints, but booooy... can you add at least one minor explanation like where should everyone start looking from?

Comment: @Eugene which big operation? There are two. For the conversion to UTF-8, a good start would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

Comment: that is pretty darn impressive, how many people do you know that deal with UTF outside BMP in their apps? I am 100% not one

Comment: @Eugene well most people encounter characters outside the BMP due to Emojis…

Comment: no no, you're right, I get it. It's just how many apps to `length()` and actually understand what it does? ultimate point is that unfortunately like many of your answers this will have only a limited audience. thank you for sharing, though

Comment: @Holger thanks for the detailed explanation. But what is the last character in your input string?  It's looking to me as an unrecognised char - `` - which looks like a vertical rectangular box with a cross in it

Comment: @PankajSinghal then, you have no suitable font, but you managed to copy the character correctly, so your system can process it. It’s a 5 with double outline (U+1D7DD). I suppose, when you google for `U+1D7DD` you will find pages with example renderings. E.g. http://graphemica.com/%F0%9D%9F%9D

Comment: Ohh. I just check it on my mac & it's looking correctly as what you said. However, When I'm looking it through my Android phone, it was being shown incorrectly.